# Azure table 'Merge' does not replace fields for which value passed is null (ex:Nullable<Date> field) C#

Tags: datetime, azure, replace, merge, nullable

Azure Table 'Merge' does not merge the value of date if the date value for that record exists in the table and if we explicitly pass null to that Nullable field on merging.

I cannot use '`Replace`' because the TableEntity defined in code is just a subset of the actual table with core fields defined and initialized. Replace will remove other dynamic fields added to it.

Answer (score 4):

What you're observing is expected behavior of [`Merge Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179392.aspx) operation. From the documentation:

> **Any properties with null values are ignored by the Merge Entity
>   operation. All other properties will be updated.**
>
> A property cannot be removed with a Merge Entity operation. To remove
>   a property from an entity, replace the entity by calling the Update
>   Entity operation.

Apart from `String` data type where you can set the value as `null`, other data types do not support `null`. Setting a value of `null` on those attributes would simply mean you do not want to store them in the entity.

I guess the only option available to you is [`Replace (Update)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179427.aspx) the entity but based on the information you provided, it looks like you can't really use that option.

Comment: Is there any workaround available. Where i can retrieve all the fields into DynamicTableEntity and update just subset of the fields with the current TableEntity record values and 'Replace' the DynamicTableEntity in the table.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a possibility. Retrieve data in a `DynamicTableEntity` and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.so far

- Entity is the current updated record which needs to be replaced in the table.(Entity record has subset of the fields in the table for which null values are passed).

Any optimization or suggestions are welcome.

Code Snippet

```
 TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(
                   TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, Entity.PartitionKey),
                           TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, Entity.RowKey)));

            DynamicTableEntity CurrTblRec = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).FirstOrDefault();
            if (CurrTblRec != null)
            {
                OperationContext OpContext = new OperationContext();
                DynamicTableEntity EntityDyn = new DynamicTableEntity();

                IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> EntityKV = TableEntity.WriteUserObject(Entity, OpContext);

                Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> ExtraFldLt = CurrTblRec.Properties.Where(x => !EntityKV.ContainsKey(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

                EntityDyn.ReadEntity(EntityKV, OpContext);

                foreach (var AdditionalField in ExtraFldLt)
                    EntityDyn.Properties.Add(AdditionalField);

                EntityDyn.PartitionKey = Entity.PartitionKey;
                EntityDyn.RowKey = Entity.RowKey;
                EntityDyn.ETag = "*";

                TableOperation ReplaceEntity = TableOperation.Replace(EntityDyn);
                tblRes = table.Execute(ReplaceEntity);
            }
            else
            {
                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(Entity);
                table.Execute(insertOperation);
            }
```